# core-plot remove decimal points from axis labels

Tags: label, core-plot

Can someone tell me how to remove the decimal points from the Axis labels? Instead of 10.0 I'd like to have only 10 showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `labelFormatter` property on the axis to a new formatter. This is a standard NSNumberFormatter object. See [Apple's class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details on the options available.

Answer (score 12):

```
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
NSNumberFormatter *Xformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[Xformatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
[Xformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
x.labelFormatter = Xformatter;
[Xformatter release];
```

This will take care of the decimals on the x axis as well as add commas with NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle.  You will need to do the same for the y axis.

There are a ton of things you can do with NSNumberFormatter, including converting numbers into dollars using:

```
[Xformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
//this will add a decimal point again if you put this in the code above
```

Play around with the Esc key to see all formatting available for setNumberStyle or other methods.