# Round it the value of x and y

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-plot, xcode4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [core-plot remove decimal points from axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519901/core-plot-remove-decimal-points-from-axis-labels)

I 'am building a `Scatterplot` with the help of Core Plot 1.0 version. The Graphs X and the Y value are being printing like `15.0,18.0`,etc..  instead of 15 18 and so on. How can I round  the value???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just cast your float values to int.

`int newValue = (int)floatValue;`

Comment: I 've done that Already but I think its belongs to Core plot(Framework) Library bundle. Because I ve had a looked in to some of .h files of Coreplot and it seems to be very complex to discover the place where the round of "plotrange x and y" is happening ..

Any ideas according to Coreplot Framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSNumber` to convert your float values.

```
float aFloatValue = 15.0;
NSNumber number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:aFloatValue];
int aRoundedInt = [number intValue];
[number release];
```

Comment: You forgot to allocate, passed an `NSString` instead of a `float` and all this in just a line of code... Hooray

Comment: you're right, I was about to edit this one :) it was meant to be an example.

Comment: Thanks and It wont print as we wanted

Answer (score -3):

i dont really understand what is your question but you can try to split your string,
With [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)
Or [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
Both can do the job one is server side and on is client side,
Have a nice day.

Comment: If you don't understand a question, don't try to answer it!

Comment: PHP and Javascript have nothing to do with this question....

Comment: i am sorry i jest wanted to help.